# createSVGPoint() and new SVG.Point()

Tags: svg.js

createSVGPoint()`i get`SVGPoint {x: 0, y: 0}`however using svg.js syntax with`new SVG.Point()`it consoles`ot {x: 0, y: 0}`

Using svg.js method im not able to call matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse())

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong method. To perform a matrix transform using svg.js use the following code:

```
const transfomedPt = svgPt.transform(svgElement.getScreenCTM().inverse())
```

Comment: If you only want to get the point of an element in screen coordinates, you can use `const transformedPt = element.point(x, y)`

Comment: Hi does element have to be a svg.js element or a DOM element e.target?

Comment: Svg.js ofc. The native Dom elements don't have that method